# Center an image thats on a square thats rotated 45deg(or on a diamond shape background) css

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to center an image in the center of a diamond shaped background. Is there a way to do it using css?

```
<div class="categories">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="options">
            <div class="img">
                <img src="images/beverages.png" alt="">

            </div>
            <!-- <h2>beverages</h2> -->
        </div>
```

here's the scss.....

```
.categories{
    @extend .clr;
    .content{
        width:68.5%;
        margin:0 auto;
        .options{
            position:relative;
            text-align:center;
            margin-top:104px;
            margin-right:23%;
            float:left;
            background-color:$babyblue;
            width:169px;
            height:169px;
            @include rotate;
            &:nth-child(2n){
                background-color:$lightyellow;


            }
            &:nth-child(3n){
                margin-right:0;
            }
            &:after{
                background-image:url("images/beverages.png");
            }
        }
        .img{
            //padding-top:26px;
            position:absolute;
            transform:rotate(-45deg);
            h2{
                text-align:center;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

so basically i have a square with a color background that has been rotated 45 deg to make it a diamond and i want to center an image on top of that diamond. I have looked and tried a couple of things but none seem to work the way I need it to work. Any suggestions would help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use `text-align:center;` and rotate the image 45deg in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want to do you just need to make the image container `.img` properly centered within the diamond shape, here's what you need to modify:

```
.categories .content .img {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 169px;
}
```

Additionally, if you want the image rotated properly, you should add:

```
.img img {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```